# How to show mobile-menu in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, sass

How do I show the mobile-menu when the screen is a certain size? 
It works for the main-menu I have, but not for the mobile-menu.

I tried added two IF statements in my header class, but when I reduce my screen size, only the main-menu disappears while the mobile-menu doesn't appear.

```php
    if(has_nav_menu('top-menu'))
    {
        wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-menu', 'menu_class' => 
     'top-menu'));
    }
    else if(has_nav_menu('mobile-menu'))
    {
         wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-menu', 'menu_class' => 
         'mobile-menu'));
    }
```

Since in my SCSS, I have the top-menu only appear above 960px, I expected the mobile-menu to appear.

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without more information. If your site is available somewhere, share the URL and we might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

When you add the menu using wp_nav_menu() function, make sure to add two IF Statements rather than one if one else if.

```
if(has_nav_menu('top-menu'))
{
    wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-menu', 'menu_class' => 
 'top-menu'));
}
if(has_nav_menu('mobile-menu'))
{
     wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'mobile-menu', 'menu_class' => 
     'mobile-menu'));
}
```

Comment: To clarify for others, the menu is being generated on the server side via PHP. When there is an `if/else`, the php is only going to generate the menu for the first successful `if` or default to `else`. Which was what was originally happening, `top-menu` was generated while `mobile-menu` was not because `top-menu` existed.

Comment: To the left of a comment, there is an up arrow. Because you need to have 50 rep to comment on questions and answers besides your own and I'm guessing the upvote option will not appear for you until you do have 50 rep.